# Cellular automaton to map one vector to another in a special way

Tags: cellular-automata

I have 2 vectors:

Vector J of dimensionality N

Vector K of dimensionality M

M >> N by order(s) of magnitude.

I need to find a cellular automaton G:

K -> G -> J

G however needs to be such that  any minor change to K has some probability of having no effect on J, or having a very minor effect, or having a major/total effect, etc...

G would very likely need to have a ruleset which is derived in part from K itself.

The idea came from DNA, consider K to be DNA and J to be a set of parameters describing an organism. I have spent many hours trying to find a way to do this and I always hit a solid wall, I cannot get the most important property of all to work: Minor changes to K have to have a high probability of either doing nothing to J or having a very small effect. In my attempts the effect is always total, it's as if I'm getting some kind of hashing algorithm.

Comment: Could you share the code you have tried so far? I have a hard time conceptualizing your problem, perhaps code would make it clearer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!